# Should HOLD pin be grounded in a macronix MX35LF1GE4AB chip if I only want to read data from it?

Tags: spi, pinout

I have a Macronix [MX35LF1GE4AB](https://static6.arrow.com/aropdfconversion/d3cc88a78401b520b99e5db36139faaa06978868/1380031917002306mx35lf1ge4ab203v201gb20v1.5.pdf) NAND Flash and I want to read its contents using an rarpberry pi.

But I have trouble on how to wire the HOLD pin. Should I ground it. What I want it to read data from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HOLD# is active low. If you set it low, it will set the chip in hold mode which makes it to ignore the communication interface. So if you want to communicate with the chip, don't set it low.